# Store a TextField value inside a variable in MaterialUI/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a TextField and would like to take the input and store it in a variable.

```
<TextField
  id="output_elevator-amount"
  label="Elevator amount"
  color="primary"
  // variant="outlined"
  type="number"
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true
  }}
  InputProps={{
    readOnly: true
  }}
  onChange={(event) => {
    setAmount(parseInt(event.target.value));
  }}
/>
```

When I was working with javascript and html I did something like this but now with typescript/MUI/React I'm not sure what to do.

```
let elevatorAmt = (document.getElementById('output_elevator-amount') as HTMLInputElement);
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to store "somewhere" the variable inputed via `onChange`, you are already doing by setting `setAmount`.
I am assuming you are using this `[amount, setAmount] = useState('')`. Try console logging `amount`

Comment: thanks for your reply, you are right, I just noticed amount is never used, should I use it in the textfield? I'm really new to this sorry @Magofoco

Comment: You can use it in the textfield as `value={amount}` but you can use it anywhere without the scope `{....}` where `amount` is defined

Comment: Nice! If the answer solved your problem, can you mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store "somewhere" the variable inputed via onChange, you are already doing by setting `setAmount`.

I am assuming you are using this `[amount, setAmount] = useState('')`. Try console logging `amount` and use it where you need.